# Error or exceptions saving a .txt file (Java)

Tags: java, file, exception, processing, stringbuilder

I run the following piece of Processing (Java) code inside a bigger loop. These lines save a string in a .txt file called `kinectDEM.tmp`, before doing that, the old file is renamed to `kinectDEM1.txt` and the new one (`kinectDEM.tmp`) is renamed to `kinectDEM0.txt`.

It works fine but sometimes it get stuck and the kinectDEM1.txt file disappears, the code still work but doesn't save the .txt files. No error message appears.
Is there something wrong saving .txt files in that way?

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import SimpleOpenNI.*;
import java.util.*;
SimpleOpenNI kinect;
List<int[]> previousKinectValues = new LinkedList<int[]>();
int numPreviousToConsider = 60;
void setup()
{
  size(640, 480);
  kinect = new SimpleOpenNI(this);
  kinect.enableDepth();
  frameRate(60);
}
int precedente = millis();
void draw()
{
  kinect.update();
  PImage depthImage = kinect.depthImage();
  image(depthImage, 0, 0);
  int[] newDepthValues = kinect.depthMap();

  previousKinectValues.add(newDepthValues);
  if (previousKinectValues.size() > numPreviousToConsider) {
    previousKinectValues.remove(0);
  }
  int[] depthValues = average(previousKinectValues);
  depthValues = reverse(depthValues);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  Deque<Integer> row = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  int kinectheight = 770; // kinect distance from the baselevel [mm]
  int scaleFactor = 1;
  int pixelsPerRow = 640;
  int pixelsToSkip = 40;
  int rowNum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < depthValues.length; i++) {
    if (i > 0 && i == (rowNum + 1) * pixelsPerRow) {
      fillStringBuilder(sb, row);
      rowNum++;
      sb.append("\n");
      row = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }
    if (i < ((rowNum+1) * pixelsPerRow) - pixelsToSkip) {
    //if (i >= (rowNum * pixelsPerRow) + pixelsToSkip) {
      row.addFirst((kinectheight - depthValues[i]) * scaleFactor);
    }
  }
  fillStringBuilder(sb, row);
  String kinectDEM = sb.toString();
  final String[] txt= new String[1]; //creates a string array of 2 elements
  int savingtimestep = 2000;  // time step in millisec between each saving
  if (millis() > precedente + savingtimestep) {
    txt[0] = "ncols         600\nnrows         480\nxllcorner     0\nyllcorner     0\ncellsize      1\nNODATA_value  10\n" +kinectDEM;
    saveStrings("kinectDEM0.tmp", txt);
    precedente = millis();
    //  delete the old .txt file, from kinectDEM1 to kinectDEMtrash
    File f = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM1.txt"));
    boolean success = f.delete();

    //  rename the old .txt file, from kinectDEM0 to kinectDEM1
    File oldName1 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.txt"));
    File newName1 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM1.txt"));
    oldName1.renameTo(newName1);
    //  rename kinectDEM0.tmp file to kinectDEM0.txt
    File oldName2 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.tmp"));
    File newName2 = new File(sketchPath("kinectDEM0.txt"));
    oldName2.renameTo(newName2);

  }
}
void fillStringBuilder(StringBuilder sb, Deque<Integer> row) {
  boolean emptyRow = false;
  while (!emptyRow) {
    Integer val = row.pollFirst();
    if (val == null) {
      emptyRow = true;
    } else {
      sb.append(val);
      val = row.peekFirst();
      if (val != null) {
        sb.append(" ");
      }
    }
  }
}
int[] average(List<int[]> previousKinectValues) {
  if (previousKinectValues.size() > 0) {
    int[] first = previousKinectValues.get(0);
    int[] avg = new int[first.length];
    for (int[] prev : previousKinectValues) {
      for (int i = 0; i < prev.length; i++) {
        avg[i] += prev[i];
      }
    }
    int num = previousKinectValues.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < avg.length; i++) {
        avg[i] /= num;
    }
    return avg;
  }
  return new int[0];
}
```

Comment: Do you close your writer?

Comment: How about (mis)using log4j and a RollingFileAppender for this? Would probably be slower, though.

Comment: I just changed my question, I added the whole code

Comment: Unless it's been a while since I wrote Java code, this can't be the "whole code" as there is no `class` declaration.

Comment: This is a Processing code, which seems to be based on Java.....however this is the whole code I'm running

Comment: @Sean-Bright Processing (P5) "_is just Java, but with a new graphics and utility API along with some simplifications._" Source: https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/FAQ#why-java-or-why-such-a-java-esque-programming-language

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say **it gets stuck**?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your problem into a much smaller example sketch:

```
saveStrings("one.txt", new String[]{"ABC"});
File oldName = new File(sketchPath("one.txt"));
File newName = new File(sketchPath("two.txt"));
boolean renamed = oldName.renameTo(newName);
println(renamed);
```

In the future, please try to narrow your problem down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this.

Anyway, this program saves the text `ABC` to a file named `one.txt`. It then tries to rename `one.txt` to `two.txt`. This is exactly what you're trying to do, just without all that extra kinect code, which doesn't really have anything to do with your problem.

Please run this little example program and then view your sketch directory (Sketch > Show Sketch Folder). You'll see the `two.txt` file, and that file will contain the text `ABC` on a single line. Also notice that the program prints `true` to the console, indicating that the rename was successful. This is exactly what you'd expect.

Now, change the first line to this:

```
saveStrings("one.txt", new String[]{"XYZ"});
```

Run the program again. First notice that it prints out `false` to the console, indicating that the rename was **not** successful. Then view the sketch folder, and you'll see two text files: `one.txt` which contains `XYZ` and `two.txt` which contains `ABC`. **This is not what we expect**, and this is what's happening in your code as well.

So, what's happening is this:

We run our code, create `one.txt` containing `ABC`, then rename it to `two.txt`. We then run the code again, creating `one.txt` containing `XYZ`. We then try to rename that new file to `two.txt`, **but we can't**.

From the [Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-) for the `File#renameTo()` function, emphasis mine:

> Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and **it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.**
>
> Note that the Files class defines the move method to move or rename a file in a platform independent manner.

So it looks like the rename step is failing, becuase you can't rename a file to overwrite an existing file. Instead, we can use the [`Files#move()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) function, which allows us to specify overwrite options:

```
Files.move(oldName.toPath(), newName.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```